# Detect iPhone shutting down state and call method?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I want to call an API during iPhone shutdown/power off.
[Only applicationWillResignActive called when iPhone shuts down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126175/only-applicationwillresignactive-called-when-iphone-shuts-down)
I have gone through this URL but didn't get any solution yet.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried after looking at that URL, don't just say **didn't get any solution yet**. We can't help you without any further explanation.

Comment: The solution i got from the URL was only applicationWillResignActive is called when device turns off. I parse my API in applicationWillResignActive Method in AppDelegate but the API is not getting called during Turn off.
Also applicationWillResignActive method is getting called when we press the Home button of the Device.
But i need to call a specific API during device Turn off only. I am Unable to Detect device Turn off state or method.

Comment: Don't use several comments to add information. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31163212/edit) and add the additional information there so other people can understand the problem you're getting. Otherwise, your question will be closed.